# Is there any analogue of EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE macros in Python 2.7.6

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there any analogue of EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE macros in Python 2.7.6? If yes, how can I use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, use [`os.EX_OK`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.EX_OK).** (Unix only)

As the docs say:

> Note: The standard way to exit is `sys.exit(n).`

You can supply an exit code [listed—of the `EX_` prefix—here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.EX_OK), to [`sys.exit(n)`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sys.html#sys.exit).

Comment: "Availability: Unix" means that I can't use it on Windows? Really?

Comment: "An “Availability: Unix” note means that this function is commonly found on Unix systems. It does not make any claims about its existence on a specific operating system." - earlier on in the docs. :D

Comment: I get this error on windows 7: "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'EX_OK'", Python version 2.7.8. Any easy way to fix?